# Can I extend the Request method in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public static string FormatHostAndUrl(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        var a = session["CurrentHost"];
        var b = session["CurrentUrl"];
        var c = string.Format("http://{0}{1}", session["CurrentHost"], new Uri((string)session["currentUrl"]).PathAndQuery);
        return string.Format("http://{0}{1}", session["CurrentHost"], new Uri((string)session["currentUrl"]).PathAndQuery);
    }
```

I use this to get the exact URL including Port. With the azure system I am using this seems to be the only combination of code that gives the correct URL.

I get the session variables

```
Session["CurrentUrl"] = Request.Url.ToString();
Session["CurrentHost"] = Request.Headers["Host"];
```

What I would like to do is to extend the Request object so I can do something like this:

```
Session["TheRealURLI Need"] = Request.RealURL();
```

Is it possible to do this with an extension method? Some method that does the functionality of the FormatHostAndUrl method?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  `Request` isn't a method.  It's an object of type [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)

Comment: @Inuyasha - Request is also a property under certain circumstances in ASP.NET. Still not a method (well it sort of is), but no need to nit-pick

Comment: @M.Babcock, that property is an object of type HttpRequest...

Comment: @Inuyasha - You're right. The request property is of type HttpRequest, but technically get_Request is a method.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Now I understand that I won't be able to extend request as you pointed out it is not a method. What I am thinking to do is to make a normal method that will do what I need.

Comment: @SamanthaJ - That wasn't the point. It is possible to extend the HttpRequest class that the Request property represents.

Comment: @SamanthaJ, what?  No.... being a property or a method or whatever is *irrelevent* to extension methods.  You extend *classes*, not methods.  See my answer.

Comment: @M.Babcock, "but technically get_Request is a method."  I don't see how this is at all relevant or constructive.

Comment: What you need is called an extension method as show by *Inuyasha* in his answer. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetRealUrl(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        return "will the real url please stand up?";
    }
}
```

Edit:  The point here is you extend *classes*, even sealed ones.  *How* you get the `HttpRequest` object is irrelevant, whether it's via a `Request` property or by any other means.  You extend the type.  The property will follow suit.